# Flutter ios No podspec found for `flutter_keyboard_visibility_web` in

Tags: ios, flutter

Iam using Flutter in Mac -> Android studio and when I write pod install in the terminal. It show me

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] No podspec found for `flutter_keyboard_visibility_web` in .symlinks/plugins/flutter_keyboard_visibility_web/ios`
```

Iam using flutter from one year ago, It is the first time it happen for me.
I cannot run the app. I dont have a plugin with this name flutter_keyboard_visibility_web in pubspec

How to fix it, thanks

Comment: i'm having the same issue and the problem is some plugin in has required it and i found on my flutter_form_builder plugin has required it. i think flutter_keyboard_visibility_web plugin is having issue because it's not contains folder ios and android same as other plugin. you can see the plugins list in podspec.lock file after you run pub get.

Comment: I think flutter_typeahead plugin has flutter_keyboard_visibility as required. 
I can see in Podfile.lock there are 4 lines about  flutter_keyboard_visibility.
Can I remove these 4 lines from Podfile.lock?
I really need flutter_typeahead , its first time I facing this problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is:

1- Delete Podfile and Podfile.lock from ios folder

2- Flutter clean either from terminal
or from Android studio -> Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean

3- Pod install

4- Run the app

The solution is here:
https://github.com/MisterJimson/flutter_keyboard_visibility/issues/52

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I cleared cache on IntelliJ and it started working again.

To do this on IntelliJ:

1. From the main menu, select File | Invalidate Caches / Restart.
2. In the Invalidate Caches dialogue, select an **invalidate the caches and restart the IDE**.

Comment: I tested that, its not work. I think the problem is in flutter_typeahead because when I added #flutter_typeahead and wrote pod install it worked. But I need to use flutter_typeahead and it has a dependency with flutter_keyboard_visibility

Answer (score 0):

I know this is quite old. But I got the same error today for the **app it self**. This is happen after I updated my project to latest flutter version 3.13.6. Probably a flutter bug.

Error:

```
[!] No podspec found for `MY_APP` in `.symlinks/plugins/tournament_viewer_flutter/ios
```

So after an hours of failing, finally I decided to make a dummy podspec file under ios folder.

I made a copy of **ios/Flutter/Flutter.podspec** file to **ios/MY_APP.podspec** and change the content as follow (you can change values to yours. This is only a reference).

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'MY_APP'
  s.version          = '1.0.0'
  s.summary          = 'MY APP'
  s.homepage         = 'site link with https'
  s.license          = { :type => 'BSD' }
  s.author           = { 'MY TEAM' => 'team@myteam.com' }
  s.source           = { :git => '', :version => s.version.to_s }
  s.ios.deployment_target = '11.0'
  # Framework linking is handled by Flutter tooling, not CocoaPods.
  # Add a placeholder to satisfy `s.dependency 'Flutter'` plugin podspecs.
  s.vendored_frameworks = 'path/to/nothing'
end
```